# How to fetch data separated by comma and store it in checkbox as checked in php

Tags: php, checkbox

How to retrieve data separated by comma and store it in checkbox as checked. I'm using `explode()` so that the string data is converted into an array.

My problem is I can't get the logic behind this code. For example the data are "Parents, Grandparents, Friends" and I want to checked the checkbox depends upon that data. Thank you in advance. Here's my code not working:

```
<?php 
  $db_living_whom = explode(",", $fetch['living_whom']);
?>

<label>Living with whom</span></label>
    <div class="row">
      <?php 
       foreach ($db_living_whom as $value) {
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Parents
          <input type="checkbox" <?php if($value == "Parent") echo "checked"; ?> disabled>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Brothers & Sisters
          <input type="checkbox" <?php if($value == "Brothers & Sister") echo "checked"; ?> disabled>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Grandparents
          <input type="checkbox" <?php if($value == "Grandparents") echo "checked"; ?> disabled>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Other Relatives
          <input type="checkbox" <?php if($value == "Other Relatives") echo "checked"; ?> disabled>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Friends
          <input type="checkbox" <?php if($value == "Friends") echo "checked"; ?> disabled>
        </label>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

In that code the checkboxes load 4 times (because of foreach loop) and the "Parents, Grandparents, Friends" are not checked.

Comment: Are there any spaces before/after the words after the explode?

Comment: You might want to show us some of the values that are already in your database. There might be something in there worth looking at. So to me, the post is unclear.

Comment: Yes there are white spaces in that data @paul

Comment: Sorry for unclear post :(. I'm not too good in programming and I want to learn more @FunkFortyNiner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the foreach loop. It was duplicating your checkboxes.

I changed to [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to account for any white space and then have the effect of explode.

Then I utilized [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search $db_living_whom whether it contains the checkbox condition in question and then mark checked accordingly.

I made it work like so:

```
<?php
    $fetch = ["living_whom" => "Parents, Grandparents, Friends"];

    $db_living_whom = preg_split("/[\s*,\s*]*,+[\s*,\s*]*/", $fetch["living_whom"]);
?>

<label>Living with whom</span></label>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Parents
            <input type="checkbox" <?= (in_array("Parents", $db_living_whom)) ? "checked" : "" ?> disabled>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Brothers & Sisters
            <input type="checkbox" <?= (in_array("Brothers & Sister", $db_living_whom)) ? "checked" : "" ?> disabled>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Grandparents
            <input type="checkbox" <?= (in_array("Grandparents", $db_living_whom)) ? "checked" : "" ?> disabled>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Other Relatives
            <input type="checkbox" <?= (in_array("Other Relatives", $db_living_whom)) ? "checked" : "" ?> disabled>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">Friends
            <input type="checkbox" <?= (in_array("Friends", $db_living_whom)) ? "checked" : "" ?> disabled>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```